# How to change the Back button color in a DetailViewController?

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

I want to change the color of the back button in a DetailViewController.
I am using Swift 3 and Xcode 8.3.3; but this is not working:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.darkGray
```

What is the way to do it?

I also tried:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.darkGray
```

but to no avail.

Actually I verified in the debugger that navigationItem.backBarButtonItem is nil.

Here is the complete code for my last trial with viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.darkGray
}
```

**Here is a short step by step way to reproduce my problem:**

From Xcode 8.3.3:

- Create a new Xcode project
- Choose Master-Detail Application. You don't need Core-Data.
- Create the project.
- Inside the viewDidLoad() function of DetailViewController.swift, add one of the lines:

  ```
  self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.darkGray
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.darkGray
  ```

  You will see when you try that the Back button of the DetailViewController stays blue.

  If you see something different then something must be weird with my Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to change it with:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Hope this works for you!

**Edit:**

Once you create the project, you'll see the following in your storyboard:

[image]

I changed it to following:

[image]

Which gave me the following output:

[image]

And following is my code for `viewDidLoad()` in DetailViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    configureView()
}
```

Hope this makes it clear enough now.

Comment: Are you changing it in your `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: What exactly would you like to see?
Yes I am doing that in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Uploaded a test project which is changing the bar color: https://nofile.io/f/nRx37mfYspZ/testing.zip
I think the issue is occurring due to your .storyboard file. Just compare your .storyboard with the test project one to ensure.

Comment: I just edited my post to add a step by step way to reproduce the problem. Please take a look if you have time.

Comment: Was able to reproduce the error. Found a workaround, checkout the storyboard of this project and the `DetailViewController` of this project: https://nofile.io/f/J3kKOQCRBko/tester.zip . What I did was change the segue from navigation controller to detail directly. Please test out the project and let me know.

Comment: The Segue I see in my case has the kind "Show Detail (e.g. Replace)" and you replaced it by what exactly?

Comment: Edited my answer with the details on how to change what to see the changes. Please check.

Comment: Thanks. It works! One point: I had to change this line: "let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController" to this: "let controller = segue.destination as! DetailViewController". I wonder if Apple is aware of that. On the iPhone you can even get rid of one of the Navigation Controllers (May be not on the iPad, I haven't tried.)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have correctly embedded the navigation controller inside the storyboard and then write in viewDIDLoad of detailviewcontroller following code:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.brown
```

It is working fine

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "correctly embedded the navigation controller inside the storyboard". What to I need to check exactly? If I look all seems normal to me.

Comment: i mean to say 'go to storyboard->select view controller which you want to make initial viewcontroller->editor embed in navigationcontroller and make navigationcontroller as initial viewcontroller .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have embedded Navigation Controller properly.Also make sure you have given correct controller class to be on safer side.

[image]

In controller class just add this line-:

```
import UIKit

class First: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.darkGray
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Output-:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is what I did.

Comment: @Michel if its not working for you edit your question with more details.

Comment: I just edited my post to add a step by step way to reproduce the problem. Please take a look if you have time.

Comment: @Michel why not single view application? I created single view application , never tried master detail application.If possible please try with single view application it should work.

Comment: If you want to test my bug you have to try the same as me. With the steps I give at the end of the post it takes less than one minute. If you have the time. Beside my problem has nothing to do with a single view application.